# Multiple image upload in ionic 5 angular (Capacitor Camera) and nodejs multer

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, multer-s3

**I'm trying to upload multiple images in ionic angular app not able to send the correct payload to the API.sending data from postman working well. Back-end using nodejs multer package for handling the image upload.**

How to send correct payload from UI to backend. For web we can use form data for image upload but mobile not able to find the solution

[image: postman payload]

### In Html File

```
<ion-button fill="outline" expand="block" color="secondary" (click)="selectImageSource()">
     <ion-icon slot="start" name="camera"></ion-icon>
      Upload
 </ion-button>
```

### TS File

```
async selectImageSource() {
    const buttons = [
      {
        text: 'Choose from gallary',
        icon: 'image',
        handler: () => {
          this.addImage(CameraSource.Photos);
        }
      }
    ];

    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      header: 'Select image source',
      buttons
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }

async addImage(source: CameraSource) {
    const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 100,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
      source,
      allowEditing: false
    });

    const blobData = this.b64toBlob(image.base64String, `image/${image.format}`);
    const uploadParams = {
      userId: 'Abcd1234',
      uploadType: 'profile-pics'
    };

    this.apiService.uploadPhotos(blobData, uploadParams)
      .subscribe((img: any) => {
        console.log('Image: ', img);
      }, (err) => console.log('Eror: ', err));
  }


    b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType= '', sliceSize= 512) {
    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting multiple images you could use
`<input #file type="file" multiple (change)="onFileSelect()" />` since it works on devices as well.

And your TS file would look like this to get an array of selected files in your case images.

```
@ViewChild('file', { static: false }) public file: ElementRef;

public onFileSelect(): void {
    const fileArray: Array<File> = this.file.nativeElement.files;
}
```

Comment: android or ios it will not work as expected, for me b64toBlob function not returning anything that is causing the issue.